# how to limit the rotation of a game object in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am making a game where there is a tank that shoots some objects.
I want to rotate the gun of the tank in between the llimits of -90 to 90 degrees in "X". 
I used transform.rotate but it rotates the gun with some float values (0.0 to 1.0) and the rotation I see on the inspector is something different. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code from [Mathf](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.html) class

```
static float Clamp(float value, float min, float max);
```

e.g.

```
var angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, 90, 270);
Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle); // any value as you see fit
transform.rotation = target;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I used eularAngles to limit the rotations as follows

```
 if((gun.eulerAngles.z<90)||(gun.eulerAngles.z>270))
        {
            gun.Rotate(0,0,turnAngle);
        }
```