# Clamping rotation/quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, quaternions

still working on VR interactions, I want to be able to rotate objects but I'm facing an issue.

For instance, I want to open/close the upper part of a laptop using my hands in VR. What I'm doing to achieve this, is that I placed the forward like that :

[image: laptopForward]

I'm creating a plane using position, forward, up. Then get the closest point on plane corresponding to my VR controller, then use transform.LookAt.

This is working fine, but I want to be able to clamp the rotation, so I cannot rotate too much (see the end of the video).

I've been trying everything, using eulersAngle and Quaternion, but I'm unable to do it.

I made some helpers (the text to show the localEulerAngles, and a transform to LookAt so I don't have to use the VR headset as it's getting pretty tedious)

Here is a video showing what's going on : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfN97OpYElk

And here's my code :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class JVRLookAtRotation : MonoBehaviour, IJVRControllerInteract
{

    [SerializeField] private Transform toRotate;

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 minRotation;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 maxRotation;

    [Header("Rotation contraints")]
    [SerializeField] private bool lockX;
    [SerializeField] private bool lockY;
    [SerializeField] private bool lockZ;

    private JVRController _jvrController;
    private bool _isGrabbed;
    private Vector3 _targetPosition;
    private Vector3 _tmp;

    public Transform followTransform;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {

        /*
        if (!_isGrabbed) return;

        if (_jvrController.Grip + _jvrController.Trigger < Rules.GrabbingThreshold)
        {
            _isGrabbed = false;
            _jvrController.StopGrabbing();
            _jvrController = null;
            return;
        }

        */

        Vector3 up = toRotate.up;
        Vector3 forward = toRotate.forward;
        Vector3 pos0 = toRotate.position;
        Vector3 pos1 = pos0 + up;
        Vector3 pos2 = pos0 + forward;
        Plane p = new Plane(pos0, pos1, pos2);

        // Using followTransform just to no have to use VR, otherwise it's the controller pos
        _targetPosition = p.ClosestPointOnPlane(followTransform.position);

        toRotate.LookAt(_targetPosition, up);

        /*
        _tmp = toRotate.localEulerAngles;
        _tmp.x = Mathf.Clamp(WrapAngle(_tmp.x), minRotation.x, maxRotation.x);
        _tmp.y = WrapAngle(_tmp.y);
        _tmp.z = WrapAngle(_tmp.z);
        toRotate.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_tmp);
        */

    }

    public void JVRControllerInteract(JVRController jvrController)
    {
        if (_isGrabbed) return;
        if (!(jvrController.Grip + jvrController.Trigger > Rules.GrabbingThreshold)) return;

        _jvrController = jvrController;
        _jvrController.SetGrabbedObject(this);
        _isGrabbed = true;
    }

    private static float WrapAngle(float angle)
    {
        angle%=360;
        if(angle >180)
            return angle - 360;

        return angle;
    }

    private static float UnwrapAngle(float angle)
    {
        if(angle >=0)
            return angle;

        angle = -angle%360;

        return 360-angle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try [how to limit the rotation of a game object in unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912965/how-to-limit-the-rotation-of-a-game-object-in-unity3d) or maybe also [Unity - Clamp Rotation between arbitrary angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492004/unity-clamp-rotation-between-arbitrary-angles/43499718)?

Comment: Yes I tried things that looks a lot like what is in both answers. The big problem is (and you can see it in my video), when I reach the "top" (when the forward is pointing at Vector3.up), both Y and Z goes from 0 to 180 and X goes in reverse order and it just f**** up my clamping. Quaternions are not that easy to understand :x

Comment: Maybe I should just do one Rotate() or something instead of LookAt + trying to clamp afterward. But I've no idea how to achieve that so I can do it like I need. ( And ideally, I could use the 3 booleans "Lock" so I can chose on which axis I can/cannot rotate, but hey if I find a solution for a single axis it'll still be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the monitor's parent transform is the body/keyboard of the laptop. Local axes of the parent shown below:

[image: local axes of parent]

To describe the range of motion you can define a "center of rotation" vector (e.g., grey vector labeled C) that is local to the parent and an angle (e.g., 110 degrees, between each purple vector and the grey vector). For instance:

```
[SerializeField] private Vector3 LocalRotationRangeCenter = new Vector3(0f, 0.94f, 0.342f);
[SerializeField] private float RotationRangeExtent = 110f;
```

Then, you can take the forward vector it "wants" to go, and find the signed angle between the world direction of `RotationRangeCenter` and that point, then clamp it to ±`RotationRangeExtent`:

```
Vector3 worldRotationRangeCenter = toRotate.parent.TransformDirection(RotationRangeCenter);

Vector3 targetForward = _targetPosition - toRotate.position;

float targetAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(worldRotationRangeCenter, targetForward, 
        toRotate.right);

float clampedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngle, -RotationRangeExtent, RotationRangeExtent);
```

Then, find the direction that corresponds to that angle. Finally, rotate the monitor so that its forward aligns with the clamped forward and its right doesn't change.  You can use a cross product to find what the monitor's up would be, then use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to find the corresponding rotation:

```
Vector3 clampedForward = Quaternion.AngleAxis(clampedAngle, toRotate.right)
        * worldRotationRangeCenter;

toRotate.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(clampedForward, 
        Vector3.Cross(clampedForward, toRotate.right));
```

---

If someone tries to drag the monitor too far beyond the "boundaries" it will teleport from one limit to the other. If that's not desired behavior, you might consider interpolating from `SignedAngle(worldRotationRangecenter, targetForward, toRotate.right)` to `clampedAngle`, for a movement between the limits:

```
private float angleChangeLimit = 90f; // max angular speed

// ...

Vector3 worldRotationRangeCenter = toRotate.parent.TransformDirection(RotationRangeCenter);

Vector3 targetForward = _targetPosition - toRotate.position;

float targetAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(worldRotationRangeCenter, targetForward, 
        toRotate.right);

float clampedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngle, -RotationRangeExtent, RotationRangeExtent);

float currentAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(worldRotationRangeCenter, toRotate.forward, 
        toRotate.right);

clampedAngle = Mathf.MoveTowards(currentAngle, clampedAngle, 
        angleChangeLimit * Time.deltaTime);

Vector3 clampedForward = Quaternion.AngleAxis(clampedAngle, toRotate.right)
        * worldRotationRangeCenter;

toRotate.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(clampedForward, 
        Vector3.Cross(clampedForward, toRotate.right));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Tried implementing it and it's not working at all, I'll continue investigate and report here. Just a question though : where does these come from : private Vector3 LocalRotationRangeCenter = new Vector3(0f, 0.999f, 0.044f);
private float RotationRangeExtent = 110f; ? And when you use TransformDirection, is it just a typo and should be using LocalRotationRangeCenter ?

Comment: Ok, it's working now ! Still have no clue where does LocalRotationRangeCenter comes from though

Comment: You have to find one that works for your purpose. It should be the   halfway direction of the range of motion local to the parent transform.

Comment: @jichael the value in my example came from a mistake. it should be `LocalRotationRangeCenter = new Vector3(0f, 0.94f, 0.342f);` which is an approximation of (0, cos(20), sin(20)) because I want the halfway direction to be in the +y,+z quadrant and 20 degrees from the y axis. I've edited the answer to reflect that change.

Comment: @Jichael If it's stuck to the table, a good value might be `Vector3.up` with a `RotationRangeExtent = 90f;`

Comment: No it's working fine, I just tweaked minRotation/maxRotation so that it fit hat I wanted. Everything is fine anyway, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

@Ruzihm's answer worked with just a bit of tweaking ! I couldn't have got that myself honestly.

Here is the full code updated for VR, if anyone is interested :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class JVRLookAtRotation : MonoBehaviour, IJVRControllerInteract
{

    [SerializeField] private Transform toRotate;

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 minRotationDelta;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 maxRotationDelta;

    private JVRController _jvrController;
    private bool _isGrabbed;
    private Vector3 _targetPosition;

    // No clue where does this come from
    private Vector3 _localRotationRangeCenter = new Vector3(0, 0.999f, 0.044f);

    private void LateUpdate()
    {

        if (!_isGrabbed) return;

        if (_jvrController.Grip + _jvrController.Trigger < Rules.GrabbingThreshold)
        {
            _isGrabbed = false;
            _jvrController.StopGrabbing();
            _jvrController = null;
            return;
        }

        Vector3 up = toRotate.up;
        Vector3 forward = toRotate.forward;
        Vector3 right = toRotate.right;
        Vector3 rotatePosition = toRotate.position;
        Vector3 pos1 = rotatePosition + up;
        Vector3 pos2 = rotatePosition + forward;
        Plane p = new Plane(rotatePosition, pos1, pos2);
        _targetPosition = p.ClosestPointOnPlane(_jvrController.CurrentPositionWorld);

        Vector3 worldRotationRangeCenter = toRotate.parent.TransformDirection(_localRotationRangeCenter);
        Vector3 targetForward = _targetPosition - rotatePosition;

        float targetAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(worldRotationRangeCenter, targetForward, right);

        float clampedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngle, minRotationDelta.x, maxRotationDelta.x);

        Vector3 clampedForward = Quaternion.AngleAxis(clampedAngle, right) * worldRotationRangeCenter;

        toRotate.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(clampedForward, Vector3.Cross(clampedForward, right));

    }

    public void JVRControllerInteract(JVRController jvrController)
    {
        if (_isGrabbed) return;
        if (!(jvrController.Grip + jvrController.Trigger > Rules.GrabbingThreshold)) return;

        _jvrController = jvrController;
        _jvrController.SetGrabbedObject(this);
        _isGrabbed = true;
    }
}
```